# NSPopover and NSButton controle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, nspopover

I created a StatusBar application. It uses custom views and utilizes NSPopover to show some controls. Im familiar with the NSTextfield focus problem. This does not cause any pain. However I have a button in the NSPopover as well. This button does not receive any action and does not (visually) respond to any clicks. Any suggestions how to get the button focusable ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I am stuck with the same issue now.

Comment: unfortunately not. I think most solutions rely on building a new window that looks like a popover (with fixed positions).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invoking `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:NO]` before you display the popover?

Answer (score 0):

NSPopover does not become first responder unless there's a control that sets this (e.g. NSTextView). I assume this is not the case for NSButton, so try `[myPopover makeFirstResponder]` instead.